# load content of a page using only javavascript noe jquery

Tags: javascript, load

i working on a simple script that load users last posts in there blog and website !

the page is works well without any problem !
this is an example : http://parsclub.net/tools/widget/load-rss.php?u=reza-shady&l=5&w=200&c=4DC7FF

i want to load that link blow in external page !

for that i used this script and put it on a file

```
<?php
    $user   = trim($_GET["u"]);
    $limit  = trim($_GET["l"]);
    $width  = trim($_GET["w"]);
    $color  = trim($_GET["c"]);
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
?>
document.write('<div id="parsclub_widget"><img src="http://parsclub.net/themes/parsclub/imgs/loading_posts.gif" style="margin:20px;display:inline-block;"/></div>');

function ajaxRequest() {
    var activexmodes = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < activexmodes.length; i++) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
            } catch (e) {

            }
        }
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest()
    else return false;
}

function load_widget() {
    var mygetrequest = new ajaxRequest()
    if (mygetrequest.overrideMimeType) mygetrequest.overrideMimeType('text/html')
    mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (mygetrequest.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1) {
                var data = mygetrequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById("parsclub_widget").innerHTML = data;
            } else {
                alert("خطایی در هنگام دریافت اطلاعات رخ داده است");
            }
        }
    }

    mygetrequest.open("GET", "http://parsclub.net/tools/widget/load-rss.php?u=<?= $user ?>&l=<?= $limit ?>&w=<?= $width ?>&c=<?= $color ?>", true);
    mygetrequest.send(null);
    return false;
}

load_widget();
```

but it don't work when i put it on a external page 
you can see the result here ! 
http://up.pc-t.ir/New%20Text%20Document.html

i know i cant simply load it with jquery load() function but i want it pure JavaScript
can anyone help me with this ?

**so sorry for my bad English**

## EDIT

@merlin-denker 10x for your help i found solution for my problem by adding this headers to the load-rss.php file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

Comment: Your English is OK, except we end sentences with `.`, not `!` except when they're exciting.

Comment: Check your Javascript console. It's failing because of the AJAX Same-Origin policy. `up.pc-t.ir` can't load AJAX from `parsclub.net`.

Comment: so how can i load it ? can you show an example ?

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar already stated in a comment, the AJAX Request is failing because of the same origin policy.

The solution to this is to add a PHP-Script to your Website that simply reads the content of the other URL and echoes it.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(YOUR_URL_HERE); ?>
```

Then let your Javascript call the script that is located on the same webserver and it will work.

Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: you mean  use file_get_contents in up.pc-t.ir ? look , it's not only on pc-t.ir it's going to show the content of page on different site and **blog** i cant upload an php file on a weblog

Comment: user just put   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://parsclub.net/tools/widget/widget.php?u=reza-shady&l=5&w=200&c=4DC7FF"></script>` in there blog . not any other php file

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, put a php file on up.pc-t.ir that will read the other url. no need to put url on other peoples webspace.

Comment: i can't put files on up.pc-t.ir it's a temporary host !

Comment: The PHP file that you call via JS needs to be on the same domain as the file that has the JS in it. Any other way it will not work.

Comment: there is no way ?? instead of Ajax ? i can include load-rss.php into widget.php how can i use it on javascript ! i tried `innerHTML = "<?php include('load-rss.php') ?>"; `

Comment: That will work if load-rss.php does not contain any `"` that would break your JS-Code

Comment: why do you want to write it to the sourcecode with javascript anyway? just include the file directly...

Comment: it's a widget , parsclub.net it's a micorblog that users can share post on it (like twitter) , i want to give theme ability to show there parsclub posts in ther weblogs and sites , users can't use .php in blogging systems

Comment: Okay, I now understand. Well then you will have to output all the source-code within the JS-File. You have no chance of loading posts dynamically with AJAX from your page if the JS-code will be hosted somewhere else on a blog. If you have an error with that, check the error console. I can't tell you whats wrong with that without further information.

Comment: i'm not a javascript expert :( can i do it with json ? or smothing like that ? i have seen this before

Comment: Well you can do a lot with JSON... But you cannot load JSON from your server if the JS-Script runs on another server without the use of PHP. You will have to put all the content that shall be displayed on the other website in your JS-Code.